# Renewing DHCP lease without losing static IPs? (dhclient removes static IPs)

Tags: networking, dhcp, static-ip, dhclient

I have this interface, with DHCP and some static IPs:

```
$ ip addr
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e0:d5:5e:13:19:d9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.208/24 scope global enp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.88.87/24 scope global enp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.1.15/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global secondary enp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::e2d5:5eff:fe13:19d9/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

e.g. 192.168.88.87

When I lose the Internet, I try to get it back with this command:

```
sudo dhclient -r enp3s0 && sudo dhclient enp3s0
```

However, this removes all my static IPs from the interface:

```
$ ip addr
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e0:d5:5e:13:19:d9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.208/24 scope global enp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::e2d5:5eff:fe13:19d9/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Any ideas how to renew the DHCP lease without losing my static IPs, or having to manually add them after?

Comment: Do you really need to mix and match DHCP and static on the same interface?   Might be easier to create virtual interfaces or something.